# Problems creating a get_time() function in C

Tags: c, c89

I have this simple function:

```
char*
get_time()
{
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*10); /* HOW TO FREE IT ? */
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(buffer,10,"%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);

    return buffer;
}
```

The issue is with `strftime()` which requires a `char*` and I can't `free(buffer);` before returning his content. What could I do?

The macro where I use the function:

```
#define log_info(msg) printf("%s [INFO ] - %s\n",get_time(), (msg))
```

Comment: give buffer as an argument of get_time and use a static buffer in the caller

Comment: That's the nature of C: if a function needs to return a string, you have to make the caller allocate room for it and pass in a buffer. The other option that might work here is to return a fixed-sized structure.

Comment: or make it clear that the caller must free buffer, this is common too

Comment: @Ôrel That's a solution, but unfortunately not for me. I use the function in some macros. Couldn't I return a `char[]` ?

Comment: I don't get the link between macro and my solution. You can use a global variable. `static char g_buffer[10]`

Comment: I have updated mys proposition.

Comment: What's wrong with calling the function from macros? Simply have the macro `free()` the returned buffer.

Comment: update done with the macro

Comment: now the usage is clear - use a static buffer (if you are single threaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
static char g_buffer[10];                                                      

#define log_info(msg)                               \                          
    do {                                            \                          
    get_time();                                     \                          
    printf("%s [INFO ] - %s\n", g_buffer, (msg));   \                          
    g_buffer[0] = '\0';                             \                          
    } while (0)                                                                

static int get_time()                                                          
{                                                                              
    time_t rawtime;                                                            
    struct tm * timeinfo;                                                      

    time(&rawtime);                                                            
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);                                            
    strftime(g_buffer,sizeof(g_buffer),"%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);                   

    return 0;                                                                  
}                                                                              

int main(void) {                                                               
    log_info("test");                                                          
    return 0;                                                                  
}
```

But and don't get the need of a macro, a function will do the job

Comment: You are right. I don't need a macro, better a function.

Answer (score 0):

For variable-sized strings, you have no choice but having the caller allocate and pass in a buffer. But for a fixed size like this, you can use a structure:

```
struct mytime {
    char buf[12];
}

struct mytime get_time() {
    struct mytime r;
    . . .
    strftime(r.buf, 10, "%H:%M:%S", timeinfo);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I added the macro where I need the function.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right, or you have requirements you didn't mention. If you post complete code, I might be able to help.